# rewrite directory tree

Tags: nginx

i would like to serve static files with `nginx`.
i get static pages via `wget` and the root of the directory tree is page protocol. ie for *http://www.example.com/* :

```
http
└── www.example.com
    └── index.html
```

i would like to be able to serve pages like this :
*http://website.com/page/[http://www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/_)*
to render *http://website.com/page/http/www.example.com/*

what is the `nginx` configuration for this ?

update: i tried this : `rewrite ^(.+)://(.+)$ $1/$2 last;` but it doesn't work

Comment: i think it is only because i'm not allowed to use :// in url :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then you are most likely looking for a forward proxy like Squid, Nginx is a reverse proxy and is not really made for situations like this.

Comment: maybe there are better tools but for now i would like to limit my project to nginx. are you sure there is no way to do it with nginx ?

Comment: Research what a forward proxy is, if that is indeed what you need then no you cannot do it with Nginx as it is written to be a reverse proxy only.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive docs: *The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash.*

You can prevent nginx from merging slashes at `server` block level with [`merge_slashes`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes), although I would recommend caution doing such a thing and would generally advise against it.

Your regular expression does not match the normalized URI. You would need to use:

```
rewrite ^(.+):/(.+)$ $1/$2 last;
```

As a supplementary piece of advice, you might want to have a look at your regular expression to replace the generic `.` catch-all characters by more specific classes or sets, so its behavior is better defined.